# Limit number of model object page views for an anonymous user until they have to sign up (Django)?

Tags: javascript, django, session, cookies

I'm trying to track the number of views an **anonymous** (Non-authenticated) user makes on my model object detail pages (Map pages) so that I can redirect them to the sign up page after they view the pages ~5 times.

For example: the anonymous user gets 5 free map views before having to sign up (Or these pages will be unaccessible).

Not sure if I should use cookies, sessions, or just some kind of javascript for this. I can't really wrap my head around it.

A point in any direction would be great, thanks!

Comment: This is far from being a trivial question. Many strategies exist, but none will be able to perfectly prevent anonymous users to access what they want if they feel motivated and even more if they fell challenged.

Comment: anonymous user is not anonymous anymore if you can catch his fifth visit) Probably you can rethink the logic of app and, for example, show motivating popup on every visit?

Comment: Thanks guys for the advice! I'm still trying to figure out the best method so both of your inputs help!

Comment: One thing I know for sure is the users on the site aren't tech savvy so anything would be better than nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a foolproof method as there are ways around it, but for a normal web-user/ non-dev you should be able to increment session for anonymous users according to the documents:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/

And you could likely do something like:

```
if request.session["page_views"] > 4:
    return redirect('wherever')
else:
   request.session["page_views"] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to implement this and see how it goes

Comment: I used a variation of this and it worked for what I need at the moment. Cheers!